# %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_shutdown_ms.txt

Tags: windows, google-chrome, shutdown

I was just playing around with Chrome and was wondering if anyone know what does the number in `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_shutdown_ms.txt` mean ?

Everytime I shutdown chrome, it will change, so I'd expect the number inside it to mean *the number of milliseconds it takes to shutdown chrome..

But it doesn't seem to be so because my number writes `1000+`, sometimes even `2000+` and yet it doesn't actually even take a second to shutdown chrome, so obviously that number couldn't be the amount of milliseconds it takes to shutdown chrome.

Does anyone know what does that number mean?

Comment: The chrome window disappearing does not mean that chrome has shutdown , if you check you task manager u can see that chrome process are still running after yo have closed the browser

Comment: @Shark hey yes I'm aware of that but even the Chrome process had been terminated within < 500 milliseconds hence the question

Comment: You should ask on the Google Chrome forums.

Answer (score 1):

According to the chromius sources, which can be searched [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search) for `chrome_shutdown_ms.txt`, this is exactly the shutdown time of Chrome (at least, for a part of its processes). If you see that chrome processes disappear from process list faster than the logged time, then there could be a bunch of reasons for this, but they are hard to deduce without additional testing.